# How to set the image background for a mobile app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

There is such a mobile app [Study Bunny: Focus Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superbyte.studybunny). And there is such a possibility to change the background. And I have a question, how can something like this be realized? So that it would be adaptive for mobiles and tablets in vertical orientation. But that the image itself is not stretched and not narrowed.

I understand it is necessary to draw a different background for each screen size. And just change it to fit the screen size. Is that right or not? Or is there some other way, easier, not to draw a background for each screen size, but to use one size?

I will be glad to any advice)

Answer (score -2):

You're touching upon an essential aspect of mobile app design: creating adaptive UIs that look good on multiple screen sizes and resolutions without distorting content. Here's an overview of how this can be achieved:

**1. 9-Patch Images:**
A 9-Patch image is a resizable bitmap resource that can be used as background or other images on the device. It works by defining stretchable and static areas. As a result, the image can resize to accommodate the content without distorting vital parts of the image.

**2. Scalable Vector Graphics (SVGs):**
Vector images are not based on pixels but on paths, which means they can be scaled indefinitely without losing quality. This is particularly useful for simple backgrounds or logos. You can create one SVG file, and it will scale appropriately across different screen sizes.

**3. Aspect Fit & Fill:**
Aspect Fill: This scales the image to fill the size of the view. Some parts of the image may extend beyond the bounds of the view, but the aspect ratio will be maintained.
Aspect Fit: This scales the image to fit within the size of the view, maintaining the aspect ratio. As a result, some areas of the view might remain empty.
**4. Using Media Queries:**
If you're using a platform like Flutter or web technologies to build your app, you can utilize media queries to detect screen size and apply styles or select images accordingly.

**5. Background with Patterns or Gradients:**
Instead of using complex images, consider using patterns or gradients. They can easily be generated to fit any screen size without distortion.

**6. Multiple Resolution Images:**
While not a single-image solution, some developers provide images tailored for different screen densities (like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc., in Android). It’s more about screen density than screen size, ensuring clarity and sharpness.

**Tips:**
Safe Area: Ensure vital components of your background (like logos or specific visuals) remain in the 'safe area' to avoid getting cropped on different devices.
Testing: Always test the background on multiple devices or emulators to ensure it looks as intended.
In conclusion, while it's possible to create multiple backgrounds for each screen size, modern design practices and tools allow for adaptive designs that can scale across devices. The best approach depends on the specific background design, the platforms you're targeting, and your app's requirements.

Comment: This looks like chatGPT answer to me . see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1